# MYSQL trim string without cutting off midword

Tags: mysql, concatenation, trim

I have a database with a description field. I want to be able to return only part of that field (150 chars), however I don't want to cut them off mid-word. (like th...

Any ideas how this would be accomplished?

At the moment I have:

```
SELECT  e.*, e.id as event_id, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(e.description,1, 100),'...') AS short_description, FROM events e
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a database function that manipulates the string, cutting it off if too long and addding the "...".

Call the funcion from your SELECT statement (assuming you call the function LIMIT_TEXT):

```
SELECT  e.*, e.id as event_id, LIMIT_TEXT(e.description, 100, '...') AS short_description, FROM events e
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  e.*, e.id as event_id,
  CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(e.description, 101, 1)=' '
            OR CHAR_LENGTH(e.description)<=100
  THEN
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(e.description, 1, 100))
  ELSE
    SUBSTRING(e.description, 1,
              100-LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(e.description, 1, 100))))
  END as short_description
FROM
  events e
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9049e/1).